# Late answer changing For loop to While

Tags: discussion

While I was reviewing late answers, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764514/trailing-zeroes-in-a-factorial/26323721#26323721) answer which is similar to the previous answer but the `for` loop is changed to a `while` loop. Should I flag such answers? If I should flag it which flag should I use?

**EDIT**

The [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4132936/rana-rajput?tab=answers&sort=votes) has posted the same answer on various similar questions

Comment: I flagged the user for posing 6 duplicate answers.

Comment: Yeah I was just looking at his activity and got suspicious and was about ask what to do. How do you flag a user?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Is this really a reason for flagging?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions)

Comment: Is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977727/the-number-of-trailing-zeros-in-a-factorial-of-a-given-number-ruby/26323556#26323556) even valid Ruby?

Comment: @Srikanth: By flagging one of their posts as "Other...", and explaining the issue in the flag message.

Comment: If they change too much of the author's intent (using a different mechanism is certainly that), then it should be flagged and reverted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Technically, they do ([mostly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274307/late-answer-changing-for-loop-to-while#comment104986_274307)) look like valid answers.  They're all identical, but that's just because the questions are asking essentially the same thing.  We might want to close some of those as duplicates (but do keep [Dr. Strangedupe](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) in mind while doing so).

That said, they're not particularly *good* answers.  For one thing, because they're just code dumps with no explanation.  For another, because they're not customized to fit the specific questions, as you generally should do if posting essentially the same answer several times.  Finally, they're also not very good answers because, in many cases, they're redundant to other answers already posted earlier.

Fortunately, there's usually no urgent need to do anything about such answers: being posted on old questions, mostly with existing good answers, they're unlikely to gather any significant number of upvotes.  They'll just sit there at the bottom of the page, at zero score, contributing little but also costing little.

Still, if you *want* to do something, here are a few possible options:

- Pick the question with the best answer, and vote to close (some of) the others as duplicates of it.  If necessary, edit the target question itself into shape first.
- If you feel the answers are redundant or unsuitable for the question, downvote them.  Preferably also leave a comment explainin why you downvoted, to avoid inviting sympathy upvotes.
- If the answers are *really* redundant, flag them for moderator attention.  I believe it's standard practice for mods to delete redundant answers that contribute absolutely nothing new to the thread.

  You do need to be *very* clear when flagging such answers, and you should only do so when the uselessness of the answer is fairly obvious.  Mods don't generally like to click through to the question thread and wade through a whole bunch of other answers just to figure out whether your flag is valid or not.  Preferably, provide a direct link to a single other answer that contains clearly equivalent but better code.
- Alternatively, if the answer is *not* completely reduntant, you might want to consider simply editing it into shape.  In this case, that could involve removing the pointless header and adding a brief explanation of what the code does (or, perhaps, a link to a better answer that *does* explain it).
- Finally, if none of the options above looks good, you could also consider simply posting your own, better answer.  *Good* new answers to old question *do* often earn upvotes, especially if, as here, the question happens to be subject to the "meta effect".